# GIT quotients under equivariant blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, geometric-invariant-theory

I am looking for a reference. Let $X$ be a (complex projective) variety and $V$ some subvariety invariant under the action of a reductive group $G$. Has it been studied in general how blowing up $X$ along $V$ affects the GIT quotients of $X$ by $G$? Or anything along these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result can be found as Lemma 3.11 of the following article-

Partial Desingularisations of Quotients of Nonsingular Varieties and their Betti Numbers

by Kirwan.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971369?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents